# Finding lower central series of Lie algebra L

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I have a worked example of finding the lower central series but can't get my head around it.

So L= Hn, the nth Heisenberg Lie Algebra. Then L has basis: {u1,...,un, v1,...vn, z} and:

[ui, uj]=[vi, vj]=0,

[ui, vj]= -[vj, ui] = (delta ij)z and

z is in the centre of L, that is [z, a]=[a, z] for all a element of L.

The following working is then given to find the lower central series:

L^2=span{[x,y] / x,y elements of L}

=span{ [ui, vj], [ui, uj], [vi, vj], [z,x] }

=span{z} = kz

Im not sure how it gets from the first line to the second line. Why does taking all possible pairs of elements from the basis work?

Then:

L^3

=[L,L^2]

=[L, z]
={0}

So we have L^3={0} and we are done.

For both L^2, L^3 i dont understand the logic of each step. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

U mentioned that L has a $\underline{basis}$: {u1,...,un, v1,...vn, z}. 
For $x\in L$, you can write : $x=x^zz+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^u_iu_i +x^v_iv_i$ where $x^z, x^u_i$ and $x^v_i$ are scalars. Do the same for $y$, and span $[x,y]$ using the bilinearity (and skew symmetry) of the bracket :
$$[x,y]= \sum_{i,j} \alpha^z_{i}[z,u_i]+\alpha^z_{j}[z,u_j] + \beta_{ij}[u_i,v_j] $$.

where $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s are scalars. This shows that $L_2=span\{ [u_i, v_j],[z,u_i],[z,v_i] \}=span\{z\}$ ...

$L_3=\{[x,y]; x\in L\: ,\: y\in L2 \}$. Since $L_2=span\{z\}$, $y \in L_2$ can be written $y=\alpha z$, with $\alpha$ a scalar. Since z is central you get :
$$L_3=\{[x,\alpha z];x\in L ,\:\alpha\: scalar\}=\{0\}$$.